# Actively Scanning for Different File Date in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, scanning

I am trying to make a Python script that actively scans a log for new credentials and fixing them (Ettercap outputs, etc.), but I'm not getting the output I want. I am a complete noob at while loops, and I don't even think it's the way to go, but here is what I have:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#include <stdio.h>
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import time
while True:
    username_list = list(subprocess.check_output("cat pooky.log | grep 'USER: ' | awk '{print $6}'", shell=True))
    password_list = list(subprocess.check_output("cat pooky.log | grep 'PASS: ' | awk '{print $8}'", shell=True))
    url = subprocess.check_output("cat pooky.log | grep 'INFO: ' | awk '{print $10}'", shell=True)
    if "+" in username_list:
        fix1 = username_list.index('+')
        username_list[fix1] = " "
    username = "".join(username_list)
    if "+" in password_list:
        fix2 = password_list.index('+')
        password_list[fix2] = " "
    old = os.stat("pooky.log").st_mtime
    if os.stat("pooky.log").st_mtime != old:
        username += username
        password += password
        url += url
        print "New credentials found."
    time.sleep(1)
    break
```

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier when you use 're.findall ()' ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set any condition to break your loop so it will run indefinitely. If you want to structure this as a while loop and you don't want it it to run forever, you need to add a break statement somewhere:

```
while True:
    # do stuff
    if something == somethingElse:
        break
```

As for the rest of your code, it's hard to say what is wrong with it without having some example inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I actually truncated this on accident. I had a break at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of your code that only reads the file once per loop (not three times):

```
import os
import time

log_file = "pooky.log"
old_time = None
while True:
    username_list = []
    password_list = []
    url_list = []
    log_fh = open(log_file)
    for line in log_fh:
        words = line.split()
        if words[5] == 'USER:':
            username_list.append(words[6].replace('+', ' '))
        if words[7] == 'PASS:':
            password_list.append(words[8].replace('+', ' '))
        if words[9] == 'INFO:':
            url_list.append(words[10])
    close(log_fh)
    new_time = os.stat(log_file).st_mtime
    if old_time is not None and new_time != old_time:
        print "New credentials found."
        old_time = new_time
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: No, this isn't working/going to work because there are going to be multiple lines before the Ettercap USER:, PASS:, etc. lines.

Comment: Maybe you should post an example of your data; I'm not a mind reader.  :-)

Comment: Nah, I figured it out. I just tweaked my code and added a bit of yours... hours and hours of experiments... but now it works. :)